# ROG Strix Z490-I Network Driver Issues

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, bios, asus

I recently ran into an issue with my Asus z490-i Gaming motherboard where upon reinstalling windows 11 and updateing the bios, i can no longer see any wireless network adaptors (WIFI & Bluetooth) my LAN works perfectly but no matter what i do i cant seem to get the wireless adaptors to register on my computer.

I went from BIOS version 607 to 2701

any sugestions for how to fix other than doing a BIOS flashbock?

I have tried the following:

1. using all asus software available to scan for the hardware/drivers
2. using intel software to scan for missing drivers
3. downloading the drivers from asus and trying to install directly through device manager (this says installed correctly to 0 devices)
4. disabeling and re enabling the connection in bios
5. using external usb adaptors on the computer for both wifi and bluetooth work perfectly

the only thing i can think of is rolling back by bios which i dont want to do if possible as the pc seems to be running much smoother after the update